# Filter a multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP like this:

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-02-26',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Night',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 108.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 1,
    ),
    1 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-02-27',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Night',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 108.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 1,
    ),
    2 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-02-28',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Night',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 118.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 1,
    ),
    3 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-03-01',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Night',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 108.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 1,
    ),
    4 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-01-01',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Breakfast',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 12.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 2,
    ),
    5 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-01-01',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Extra bed',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 0.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 1,
    ),
    6 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-01-02',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Breakfast',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 12.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 2,
    ),
    7 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-01-02',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Extra bed',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 0.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 1,
    ),
    8 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-01-03',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Breakfast',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 12.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 2,
    ),
    9 => Array(
        'NDC_Date'     => '2017-01-03',
        'NDC_Item'     => 'Extra bed',
        'NDC_Rate'     => 0.00,
        'NDC_Quantity' => 1,
    ),
);
```

I need to merge some of the entries `only` if:

- The dates are `consecutive`.
- The `items` and `item rates` are the same.

---

Desired output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-02-26, 2017-02-27
        [NDC_Item] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 108.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-02-28
        [NDC_Item] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 118.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-03-01
        [NDC_Item] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 108.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-01-01, 2017-01-02, 2017-01-03
        [NDC_Item] => Breakfast
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 2
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-01-01, 2017-01-02, 2017-01-03
        [NDC_Item] => Extra bed
        [NDC_Rate] => 0.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
    )
)
```

---

What I have actually is the piece of code to merge the dates when the `item` and the `item-price` are the same:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($billingDatas as $item) {
    $k = $item['NDC_Item'];
    if (!isset($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $item;
    } elseif (($i = $result[$k]) 
            && $item['NDC_Rate'] == $i['NDC_Rate'] 
            && $item['NDC_Quantity'] == $i['NDC_Quantity']) {
        $result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ', '. $item['NDC_Date'];
    } else {
        $result[$k. time()] = $item;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

And another one to check if the dates are consecutive or not:

```
$dates = "2017-02-26, 2017-02-27, 2017-03-01";
$dates = explode(',', $dates);

$conseq = array(); 
$ii = 0;
$max = count($dates);

for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
    $conseq[$ii][] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates[$i]));

    if($i + 1 < $max) {
        $dif = strtotime($dates[$i + 1]) - strtotime($dates[$i]);
        if($dif >= 90000) {
            $ii++;
        }   
    }
}

print_r($conseq);
```

But how can I merge the two codes to get the new array ?

Thanks.

Comment: why you delete the same one asked yesterday, and ask the same one today???

Comment: Because I've got now the code that check for consecutive dates.

Comment: In this case, you should the old one. not reopen one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the second approach of dissecting each part, what you do is just to build on what you already have in your initial foreach loop.

First criteria in your current loop is to check the rate and then quantity. The next step is to just check the **date**.

To do that, get the current batch grouped array, explode it and get the last date. And check the current iteration date and check if that date is the consecutive day.

Idea:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($billingDatas as $item) {
    $k = $item['NDC_Item'];

    if (!isset($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $item;
    } elseif (
        ($i = $result[$k]) && 
        $item['NDC_Rate'] === $i['NDC_Rate'] && 
        $item['NDC_Quantity'] === $i['NDC_Quantity'] 
    ) {
        // additional date check
        $current_dates = explode(', ', $result[$k]['NDC_Date']); // get the comma delimited dates and explode
        $last_date = end($current_dates); // get the last date
        // then check if the current iteration date is the next day
        if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$last_date} +1 day")) === $item['NDC_Date']) {
            $result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ', '. $item['NDC_Date'];
        } else {
            $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
        }
        // rest is self-explanatory

    } else {
        $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Wow. I think you help me a lot with that. Thanks for your explanation and your time.

Comment: @user7347588 sure glad this helped